# How do I make a sub menu link become the head link in css dropdown menu without the use of javascript or jquery?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm very new to this and don't know how to use javascript or jquery and would prefer to avoid using it in all possible cases as I know it's not compatible in all browsers, takes time to load and can be disabled by users.

I've already made and designed the menu but would like the main heading in the menu to change to the submenu link when clicked on whilst keeping the rest of the menu in tact. How do I achieve this in css?

Comment: http://www.basewebmaster.com/css/simple-css-drop-down-menu.php

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://davidwalsh.name/css-target and use the css target selector (But it's not supported in IE - I haven't checked IE10 though).

but-

If you want to change the text or href attribute then, it's **not possible in pure css** (correct me if I'm wrong). You would have to use javascript. Jquery makes it easier to make your site support most used browsers, why not give it a go? I am certain if you get stuck, people on Stack overflow would gladly help you.

on a sidenote, css can also be disabled by the user (and not all browsers support all css features). Css and Javascript are in the same boat, because the browser dictates what is supported.

Comment: what jquery plugin would I be searching for? I'm not up to date with all the correct lingo as I'm self teaching myself and building a site at the same time.

Comment: Or would I be able to do it in html5?

Comment: @Marcus http://jquery.com/download/ - Here you can download Jquery. Jquery is a library that makes it easier to write javascript. I would start by learning how to create a cick event. Then figure out how to get the value from the clicked menu item. Then add this value (link in this case) to the menu header. There is much to learn and search for. But if you are doing html and css then next step is usually javascript. If you get stuck post a new question here on SO (with the specific problem). EDIT: or throw me an email.